# How can I reach a spesific member of a kivy screen inside another class?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm quite new to python. I'm trying to enable a button of a kivy screen inside a popup but I failed to adress the related screen (and therefore button of that screen) as I am outside of its class. Can you show me how I can adress it properly ? Below I try to simulate the issue as plain as possible. (If you see any other areas of development, feel free to adress.) Thanks in advance...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

popupWindow = ""

class S_Mananager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class S_Primary(Screen):
    
    def show_pop_up(self):
        global popupWindow
        popupWindow = Popup( 
            content     = pup_Pass(), 
            size_hint   = (None,None), 
            size        = (250, 300)
            )
        popupWindow.open()

class pup_Pass(BoxLayout):

    def btn_OK(self):
        global popupWindow
        popupWindow.dismiss()
        S_Mananager.get_screen("scr_primary").ids.btn_enable_me.disabled = False

class S_Secondary(Screen):
    pass

class Screens(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Screens().run()
```

KV File:

```
<pup_Pass>:

    orientation:    "vertical"
    size:           root.width, root.height
    Label:
        text:       "Label"
    Button:
        text:       "OK"
        on_release: root.btn_OK()

S_Mananager:

    S_Primary:
    S_Secondary:


<S_Primary>:
    
    name:   "win_Main"

    BoxLayout:
        id:             "scr_primary"
        orientation:    "vertical"
        size:           root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text:           'Label'
        Button:
            text:           'Button'
            on_release:     root.show_pop_up()
        Button:
            id:             "btn_enable_me"
            text:           'Enable Me by Popup !'
            on_release:     root.show_pop_up()
            disabled:       True

<S_Secondary>:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are trying to call `get_screen()` as though it were a class method, but it is an instance method. You need to call `get_screen()` through an instance of `ScreenManager`.
2. You should not use strings for `ids`.

The fix is to first change the `id` for the `Button`:

```
    Button:
        id:             btn_enable_me  # not a string
```

Then modify your python to use the instance of `ScreenManager` in your GUI:

```
def btn_OK(self):
    global popupWindow
    popupWindow.dismiss()
    App.get_running_app().root.get_screen("win_Main").ids.btn_enable_me.disabled = False
```

Note that `get_screen()` requires the `name` of a `Screen` (which should be a string), not the `id`.

Comment: Thanks John for both solution and explaination ! Have a nice day...